# Is it possible to set Hebrew value in html select tag?

Tags: html, select, cross-browser

This html select looks good on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvdfzam8/):

```
<select>
  <option value="אלף">אלף</option>
  <option value="בית">בית</option>
  <option value="גימל">גימל</option>
</select>
```

Is it guarenteed to work on all desktop browsers?

Comment: Why would it *not* work? What kinds of things are you worried about? Fonts? Writing direction? Passing data to server?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<option value="אלף<"אלף</option>` ?

Comment: Is there a "foreign-languages" tag or something like that? I couldn't find one..

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - The title says "value", so fonts obviously aren't the problem. As to the other options - I really can't guess what can go wrong.. If I had to I'd say "passing data to the server", but wouldn't want to limit the question to only that.

Comment: @OrenA perhaps you're worried how your values would appear since I think they are [Right-To-Left Hebrew text](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/right-to-left/info) ?

Comment: @Reyno - all of the above :)

Comment: @OrenA, how does this differ from “is `value="foo"`guaranteed to work?” Or from ditto about `value="æ"`. All non-Ascii characters imply that you need to consider character encodings (normally, use UTF-8), but this is in no way limited to `select` and Hebrew. Writing direction affects only the way characters are displayed, so they appear (to client-side scripts and to server-side processing) in the same logical order as in HTML source, e.g. the first character in the string “אלף” is “א”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

[image]

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and
>   may include character entities.

**But notice :**

User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:

- Replace character entities with characters,
- Ignore line feeds,
- Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.

User agents may ignore leading and trailing white space in CDATA attribute values (e.g., "   myval   " may be interpreted as "myval"). Authors should not declare attribute values with leading or trailing white space.

Hence , I don't see any reason for not to be working with older browsers.

I've tested it with IE7 for you ( pure ie7)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I don't know if it's *guaranteed* to work on *all* Desktop browsers as there are a lot of Desktop browsers out there but there are also tools to check them for compatibility. My personal favorite is [browsershots](http://browsershots.org) which gives numerous `screenshots` on what a page would look like in different browsers and different browser versions. Please note that "browsershots" might need registering a free account.

Other tools can be found by searching for `browser compatibility testing tools`

---

On another note concerning the worry about Right-To-Left texts HTML display mentioned in OP comments, you can make use of the *Bi-directional Text (Bi-Di) markup and CSS*.

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)

> Bi-directional text is text containing text in both text
>   directionalities, both right-to-left (RTL or dextrosinistral) and
>   left-to-right (LTR or sinistrodextral)

A good example of [BiDi markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/) can be:

```
<select dir="rtl" lang="he">
  <option value="אלף">אלף</option>
  <option value="בית">בית</option>
  <option value="גימל">גימל</option>
</select>
```

Another good use of BiDi could be using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) as following:

```
.hebrew {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Please note that it's recommended to use Bidi [markup instead of CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup#answer) where possible:

> You should always use dedicated bidi markup to describe your content,
>   where markup is available. Then CSS may or may not also be needed to
>   describe the meaning of that markup. This depends on whether you are
>   dealing with content that is handled by the user-agent as HTML or XML.
>   (Note that XHTML may be served as either!)